# How to fix selection Sort Swap access violation

Tags: c, sorting, assembly, x86

I'm currently trying to learn assembly and I'm trying to implement basic sorting algorithms using the language. I think I've got the logic of it down, but that could also be at fault. In either case, whenever I try to perform the swap part of the selection sort I end up with an access violation error. Based on some of the other questions regarding this topic that I've seen, the way I am implementing the swap is valid (but again, please correct me if I'm wrong). In any case, assuming the swap is right, what is causing my access violation?

Here is the code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char * arr;
    arr = new char[5];
    arr[0] = '2';
    arr[1] = '5';
    arr[2] = '1';
    arr[3] = '3';
    arr[4] = '4';
    int len = 5;

    __asm{
        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        push esi
        push edi

        mov eax, 0; //i
        mov ebx, 0; //j
        mov ecx, arr; //the array
        mov edx, 0; //min
        mov esi, len; //array length
        mov edi, len; //array len - 1
        sub edi, 1;
        mov dl, 0;
        mov dh, 0;

OUTERLOOP:
        cmp eax, edi;
        jge END_OUTER;

        mov ebx, eax;
        add ebx, 1;

        mov edx, eax;

INNERLOOP:
        cmp ebx, esi;
        jge END_INNER;

        mov al, byte ptr[ecx+ebx*1];
        mov bl, byte ptr[ecx+edx*1];

        cmp al, bl;
        jl LESS;
        jge GREATER;

LESS:
        mov edx, ebx;
        inc ebx;
        jmp INNERLOOP;
GREATER:
        inc ebx;
        jmp INNERLOOP;

END_INNER:
        cmp edx, eax;
        je PASS;
        jne SWAP;
PASS:
        inc eax;
        jmp OUTERLOOP;
SWAP:
        mov dh, [ecx+eax];
        mov dl, [ecx+edx];

        mov[ecx+eax], dl;
        mov[ecx+edx], dh;
        inc eax;
        jmp OUTERLOOP;

END_OUTER:

        pop edi
        pop esi
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop ebx
        pop eax

 }
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Error messages I get in return are the following:

```
First-chance exception at 0x012f1474 in Clean2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x004e67c8.

Unhandled exception at 0x012f1474 in Clean2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x004e67c8.
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I've changed my code and attempted to use xchg which seemed to be doing the trick. I took the advice from an answer below and decided to separate the register that I would be using for the bytes. At this point I am no longer getting any errors. This is the updated code.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char temp;
    char * arr;
    arr = new char[5];
    arr[0] = '2';
    arr[1] = '5';
    arr[2] = '1';
    arr[3] = '3';
    arr[4] = '4';
    int len = 5;

    __asm{
        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        push esi
        push edi

        mov ebx, arr; //array
        mov ecx, 0; //i
        mov edx, 0; //j
        mov esi, 0; //min
        mov edi, len; //length

OUTERLOOP:
        cmp ecx, edi;
        jge END_OUTER;

        mov edx, ecx;
        add edx, 1;

        mov esi, ecx;

INNERLOOP:
        cmp edx, edi;
        jge END_INNER;

        mov ah, byte ptr[ebx + edx];
        mov al, byte ptr[ebx + esi];

        cmp ah, al;
        jl LESS;
        jge GREATER;

LESS:
        mov esi, edx; 
        inc edx;
        jmp INNERLOOP;

GREATER:
        inc edx;
        jmp INNERLOOP;

END_INNER:
        cmp esi, ecx;
        je PASS;
        jne SWAP;
PASS:
        inc ecx;
        jmp OUTERLOOP;
SWAP:
        xchg al, [ebx + ecx];
        inc ecx;
        jmp OUTERLOOP;

END_OUTER:

        pop edi
        pop esi
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop ebx
        pop eax

 }
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n", arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However now I am getting 1, 1, 1, 3, 4 in my array instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. I will continue trying to work on this. If anyone can see what is wrong, please let me know. Thank You.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: Got it to work in the end. Turns out it was still a problem with the swap.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, it looks you are using the `eax` register for multiple things. Be aware that the byte-sized register `al` shares storage with `eax`. Specifically, when you do `mov al, ...` you overwrite the lower 8 bits of the value you had in `eax`.

Comment: Is there a way to initiate the comparison between different values on the array without moving the byte ptr to the al or bl registers?